# How to display default post with get method?

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to get an id from browser and display some pictures from the database.

If there is no "display2.php?productid=" found, then I want to display default image.

How can I do that?

Here is my code;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productlist where productid=".$_GET['productid'];
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
    {   
      if(null !==($_GET['productid']==$myRow["productid"])){
         echo "<img src=".$myRow["productid"].">"; 
      }
      else {
         echo "<img src="SELECT productimage FROM productlist where productid = 1;">"; 
      }

    }
```

Now I will make it easier to explain for you...
Check this out;

```
  //This part works without any problem 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productlista where productid=".$_GET['productid'];
$result = $mysqli->query($restwo);

while($myRow = $resulttwo->fetch_array())
{   
  if(null !==($_GET['productid']==$myRow["productid"])){
  echo "<img src=".$myRow["productimage"].">"; 
  }

  //This part below (that should be default) does not work...

  if (!$_GET){  
  echo "hello world"; }
```

Comment: Careful. [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability on line 1.

Comment: The last sql query does not work...

Comment: The last sql query doesn't work because you're not sending it to the database, you're simply placing the string into an html attribute.

Comment: how can I make it like "get the latest post from database and show the picture as default" ?

Comment: I edited my question. Please check it again..

Answer (score 0):

Asaph pointed out SQL injection. You should bind the parameter (google it), or at the minimum do this:

```
$defaultImage = "SELECT * FROM productlist WHERE imageSrc != '' OR IS NOT NULL ORDER BY productid DESC LIMIT 1";
// run the query, get the result, create a variable with default image...
$defaultImageSrc = ''; // what you get from the query result
$_GET['productid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['productid']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productlist where productid=".$_GET['productid'];
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($myRow = $result->fetch_array()) {
    if(!$myRow['imageSrc']) $myRow['imageSrc'] = $defaultImageSrc;
    echo '<img src="'.$path.'">';
}
```

Comment: it is a dynamic image. It is the latest post that will be default.  I can not set it like https://www.example.com/images/imagename.jpg.

Comment: The image has to be uploaded somewhere. Where is the image source? If  a product isn't found, and you want to display the newest product post, then you simply query the last product. like... SELECT * FROM productlist WHERE imageSrc != '' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1. This will grab the last post with an image. **I edited my answer to explain how to do this**

Answer (score 0):

If you want either `$_GET['productid']` or the `max(productid)` when `$_GET['productid']` is not set, you can use a ternary to change your sql query

```
$productid = ! empty($_GET['productid']) ? " WHERE productid = ".(int)$_GET['productid'] : " ORDER BY productid DESC LIMIT 1";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM productlist".$productid
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
    {   
         echo "<img src=".$myRow["productimage"].">"; 

    }
```

so if `isset($_GET['productid'])` your query would be

```
SELECT * FROM productlist WHERE productid = (int)$_GET['productid']
```

but if not the default would be

```
SELECT * FROM productlist  ORDER BY productid DESC LIMIT  1
```